# How do I load url into Image into DrawImage in Compose UI Android Jetpack?

Tags: android, image-processing, kotlin, drawimage, android-jetpack-compose

I can use 
`val image = +imageResource(R.drawable.header)`
and use `DrawImage(image)` to load image from Drawable Resource,

But how do I load a string url into the `DrawImage(image)`?. I've tried using Glide, but it needs to load into imageView. meanwhile `DrawImage(image)` doesn't take input from imageView.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is supported yet. Do not forget that Compose is still in dev preview.

Comment: You have to go old school and load the image yourself, take a look at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#createFromStream(java.io.InputStream,%2520java.lang.String) :-)

Comment: You can check out the gist: https://gist.github.com/anhvt52/bf9ee4a953f3421cbdbdd863650f10e8

Answer (score 25):

Staring with `1.0.x` the best way to achieve it is to use the [Coil-Compose](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#jetpack-compose) library.

Add in your `build.gradle` the dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.1")
}
```

Then just use:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter("your url"),
    contentDescription = "My content description",
)
```

This loads the `url` passed in with `rememberImagePainter`, and then displays the resulting image using the standard `Image` composable.

Comment: This does seem to be the case. The source code for com.google.accompanist.glide now contains "Accompanist-Glide is now deprecated. Consider using Coil: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose"

Comment: Wait, did I miss something or does Compose require a complete aditional library to just load an image from uri?

Answer (score 13):

### Coil for Jetpack Compose

Another option to load an image from the internet.

Add the Coil dependency to `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")
}
```

Simple use:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter("https://picsum.photos/300/300"),
    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.image_content_desc)
)
```

Don't forget to add the internet permission (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

More custom here: [Jetpack Compose - Coil Document](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/)

Answer (score 6):

A solution loading a Bitmap from the url and using the [asImageAsset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/graphics/package-summary#asimageasset) Bitmap extension method :

```
@Composable
fun loadPicture(url: String): UiState<Bitmap> {
    var bitmapState: UiState<Bitmap> by state<UiState<Bitmap>> { UiState.Loading }

    Glide.with(ContextAmbient.current)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                bitmapState = UiState.Success(resource)
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) { }
        })

    return bitmapState
}
```

Use the function with your Image() like this :

```
val loadPictureState = loadPicture(url)
if (loadPictureState is UiState.Success<Bitmap>)
    Image(loadPictureState.data.asImageAsset())
else
    Text("Loading...")
```

This snippet is using the [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library and the [UiState](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/master/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/state/UiState.kt) helper function from the [JetNews](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/master/JetNews) official Google sample for Jetpack Compose

Comment: This is outdated and can no longer be used.

Comment: (Also you might consider removing `@Composable` annotation from a non-composable function!)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `remember` to watch a bitmap, then fetch it using Glide and update it as soon as you got it.

```
var bitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null)}

Glide.with(ContextAmbient.current).asBitmap()
    .load("https://picsum.photos/200/300")
    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
             bitmap = resource
          }

          override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
      })
```

You can then use it like this:

```
if (bitmap != null )
    Image(bitmap!!.asImageAsset(), Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
else
    Text("Loading Image...")
```

(This is a modern version of [bviale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412018/4886485))

Comment: This will work, but image loading will be triggered for each re-composition. Although  Glide has it's own local cache, we better wrap the Glide code with a `LaunchedEffect`

Answer (score 3):

add

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-glide:0.10.0"
}
```

and then

```
    import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
    import com.google.accompanist.glide.rememberGlidePainter
    
    Image(
        painter = rememberGlidePainter("https://picsum.photos/300/300"),
        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.image_content_desc),
        previewPlaceholder = R.drawable.placeholder,
    )
```

for now you can use "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.1"

Answer (score 3):

For Compose 1.1.0 this snippet works like a charm, it shows the placeholder in Composable Preview:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun loadPicture(url: String, placeholder: Painter? = null): Painter? {

  var state by remember {
    mutableStateOf(placeholder)
  }

  val options: RequestOptions = RequestOptions().autoClone().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  val context = LocalContext.current
  val result = object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
    override fun onLoadCleared(p: Drawable?) {
      state = placeholder
    }

    override fun onResourceReady(
      resource: Bitmap,
      transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?,
    ) {
      state = BitmapPainter(resource.asImageBitmap())
    }
  }
  try {
    Glide.with(context)
      .asBitmap()
      .load(url)
      .apply(options)
      .into(result)
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    // Can't use LocalContext in Compose Preview
  }
  return state
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ImageItem() {
  val painter = loadPicture(
    url = item.image.fragments.image.href,
    placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.tc_ic_no_image)
  )
  if (painter != null) {
    Image(painter = painter)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the Coil dependency to build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
      implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")
}
```

Implementation in Code :

```
 Image(painter = rememberImagePainter(data = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/rr7E0NoGKxvbkb89eR1GwfoYjpA.jpg",
                                                builder = {
                                                    crossfade(true)
                                                    transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
                                                }),
                contentDescription = "Movie Poster")
```

Comment: Just a small note that the `rememberImagePainter` has been deprecated. Android Studio will refactor it for you, but just in case it fails to do so, this is the new syntax:

```
painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                    ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                        .data(data = "https://example.com/img.png")
                        .apply(block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                            crossfade(true)
                            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
                        }).build(),
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

After Jetpack's beta release, using [accompanist](https://github.com/chrisbanes/accompanist) - Utils library for Jetpack Compose is the cleanest way for the above-mentioned use case.

Comment: You linked to a third party fork, [this](https://github.com/google/accompanist) is the official Google repo for Accompanist.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of Coil - 2.1.0, *rememberImagePainter()* has been deprecated. `AsyncImage` has been introduced.

> `AsyncImage` is a composable that that executes an image request
> asynchronously and renders the result. It supports the same arguments
> as the standard Image composable and additionally it supports setting
> placeholder/error/fallback painters and onLoading/onSuccess/onError
> callbacks.

Below is a simple example of how to use `AsyncImage` to load an image from a URL:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = "https://example.com/image.jpg",
    contentDescription = null
)
```

You can check the [docs](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) for more comprehensive explanation of `AsyncImage`

Comment: [https://example.com/image.jpg](https://example.com/image.jpg) is a HTML page, so you won't see an image. Try to set another image URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use https://github.com/skydoves/landscapist

It seems to be realy good library to load images along with glide, coil, etc
It enables to override handlers to do any custom things, e.q. when you got an error or during loading phase

Answer (score 0):

Its support is still not added in Jetpack compose for some reason. But for the time being, you can use, this class

https://gist.github.com/nglauber/8a3c39db47813483d788fb2914f0f21f#file-image-kt

To use it, you need to invoke it this way :

```
Image(
  <your image url>,
  144.dp,
  96.dp
  )
}
```

You can check here to see how I used it.
https://github.com/ranjeetsinha13/gobble/blob/f8d9bca4b010adf5b4aa59cc6e56f8612ee1de09/app/src/main/java/com/rs/gobble/ui/fragments/SearchFragment.kt#L120

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very easy way to show an image from an URL.

1. Add
   `dependencies{ implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.4.0") }`
2. Just do this

   imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")

Also for a resource o file you can do this:

```
imageView.load(R.drawable.image)

imageView.load(File("/path/to/image.jpg"))
```

Requests can be configured with an optional trailing lambda:

```
imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg") {
    crossfade(true)
    placeholder(R.drawable.image)
    transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
}
```

I found this info from official coil page here: [enter link description here](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Glide,**

Follow Below Step

Add below dependancy in your app level gradle

```
def glide = "<Latest Version>"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide"
```

Create method like below in your ImageUtils class

```
@Composable
fun loadImage(url: String, @DrawableRes drawable: Int): MutableState<Bitmap?> {
    val bitmapState: MutableState<Bitmap?> = remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }

    Glide.with(LocalContext.current)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(url)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                bitmapState.value = resource
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            }

        })
    return bitmapState
}
```

Used like below wherever required in your app

```
model.imageUrl?.let { url ->
            val image = loadImage(url = url, drawable = DEFAUlT_IMAGE).value
            image?.let {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(220.dp)
                        .padding(
                            top = 10.dp,
                            bottom = 10.dp,
                            start = 5.dp,
                            end = 5.dp
                        ),
                    bitmap = image.asImageBitmap(),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
            }
        }
```

Here is an alternative approach that can also help you achieve this

1. You may refer to the [official Glide documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/compose.html) for more information. Although this approach is simpler than the one mentioned earlier, it is still in an experimental state, and therefore, I have not recommended it.
2. You can also used [Accompanist](https://github.com/chrisbanes/accompanist) for same

[Other referance](https://proandroiddev.com/loading-images-for-jetpack-compose-using-glide-coil-and-fresco-1211261a296e)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

- The easiest way to load an image in Jetpack Compose from a URL is to use `AsyncImage` from [coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil#jetpack-compose), like so:

```
@Composable
fun UrlImages(urlList:List<String>){

    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)){
        items(urlList){url ->
            AsyncImage(
                model = url,
                contentDescription = "pretty picture"
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(10.dp))
        }
    }
    
}
```

#### The tricky part

- The tricky part is trying to get all the proper aspect ratios, so the image looks normal and not compressed. For a `9/16` aspect ratio you could do this:

```
        val width = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val aspectHeight = (width * 0.5625).toInt()
```

- Usually image URLs are defined as such where we can define the aspect ration inside of them:

`https://static-cdn.fake.fakenet/fakeurl/imageendpoint-249x444.jpg`

- the `249x444` is the defined aspect ratio.