# Jetpack Compose Images loaded from URL are always black

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've used `Glide` and `Coil` to load images by URL via Jetpack Compose. 
However, images only come in black. How can I fix this?

My `Compose` and `Coil` version is the newest version.

value of `kakaoProfile.value!!.profileImageUrl!!`: https://k.kakaocdn.net/dn/IOMxT/btqYvUIVMAL/VZCdMjf01kxnkFFZFNDJ81/img_640x640.jpg

This is my code:

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
{
    if (kakaoProfile.value == null) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.AccountCircle,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
            tint = colors.primary
        ) 
    } else {
        Icon(
            painter = rememberCoilPainter(kakaoProfile.value!!.profileImageUrl!!),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)
        )
    }
}
.
.
.
Button(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(0xFF393939)),
    onClick = {
        if (kakaoProfile.value == null) {
            UserApiClient.instance.loginWithKakaoTalk(context) { token, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Login Fail", error)
                } else if (token != null) {
                    UserApiClient.instance.me { user, _ ->
                        kakaoProfile.value = user?.kakaoAccount?.profile
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            UserApiClient.instance.logout {
                kakaoProfile.value = null
            }
        }
    }
) {
    Text(
        text = if (kakaoProfile.value == null) "login" else "logout",
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

Result Screen: (oragne circle is `Icon`)
[problem screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECNf2.png)

Comment: What is kakaoProfile?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I used social messenger login API. The `kakaoProfile` variable is the login result value of the social messenger, and the profile information object of the corresponding account is entered. `kakaoProfile.value!!.profileImageUrl!!` the value of is a link to the profile picture of the logged-in account(like this: https://k.kakaocdn.net/dn/IOMxT/btqYvUIVMAL/VZCdMjf01kxnkFFZFNDJ81/img_640x640.jpg). declare: `val kakaoProfile = remember { mutableStateOf<Profile?>(null) }`

Comment: Did you check if `kakaoProfile.value` or `profileImageUrl` are null?

Comment: @Marat I checked that's value is `https://k.kakaocdn.net/dn/IOMxT/btqYvUIVMAL/VZCdMjf01kxnkFFZFNDJ81/img_640x640.jpg`. (not null)

Comment: did you try loading another image? like hardcode a simple image

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've tried another image with a local storage URI. But it's the same result. (tint all black)

Comment: I haven't played much with Compose since I have a full-time job and who has time to play with Alpha stuff? :D but.. could it be that `Icon` is the culprit here? Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594262/how-do-i-load-url-into-image-into-drawimage-in-compose-ui-android-jetpack

Comment: @MartinMarconcini The image is not entirely black, but the shape of the image appears, and all of these images are displayed in black.(like: `app:tint="#000"`) I'll refer to the link you attached. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Get rid of the tint on your Icon.

```
Icon(
  painter = rememberImagePainter(imageURL),
  contentDescription = null,
  modifier = Modifier.size(42.dp),
  tint = Color.Unspecified
)
```

Comment: Should be mark as a write answer!

Comment: Should be mark as a write answer! (2)

Comment: Why is there tint by default which you need to undo??

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same problem and I needed to change Icon to Image - seems Icons are black and white (shapes) in compose.